# Is it possible to use inheritance in Foxx models?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I am developing a REST API using ArangoDB and Foxx. A pattern that keeps coming back in multiple models is the following:

```
const NewAccount = Foxx.Model.extend({
schema: {
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    ... multiple properties
}});
```

When I store the model in the database, I want to add properties like the creation timestamp, the status of the account, ... .

```
const Account = Foxx.Model.extend({
schema: {
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    ... multiple properties,
    created: Joi.number().integer().required().default(Date.now, 'Current date'),
    status: Joi.number().integer().required()
}});
```

**question:**
Is there a way to let the *Account* model inherit all properties from the *NewAccount* model, so I only have to define the *created* and *status* properties?

Secondly, is there an efficient and easy way to copy all properties from a *NewAccount* instance into an *Account* instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct support for extending schemas via inheritance. However schemas are just objects, so you can extend them like any other object, for example using `_.extend`:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var baseAccountSchema = {
  // ...
};
var extendedAccountSchema = _.extend({}, baseAccountSchema, {
  // ...
});
var NewAccount = Foxx.Model.extend({
  schema: baseAccountSchema
});
var Account = Foxx.Model.extend({
  schema: extendedAccountSchema
});
```